# Access Denied Error: /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?cs=65001

Tags: sharepoint

We are getting the following Access Denied Error, whenever we edit the view of any document library or any list etc., or change any properties, it takes to the following URL with the message:

URL: /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001

Error Message: Access Denied Error:  You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Logs Message: w3wp.exe (0x12B4)                        0x0F0C Windows SharePoint Services    General                        6t8b Verbose  Looking up context  site ://me.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll in the farm XYZ.

Answer (score 1):

in web.config
set trace enabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have tampered 15/ISAPI/Web.config